# Displaying a photo from url

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, textures, sprite

I want to get a photo from my homepage and display it. And it (kind of) works. But sometimes it takes min 10 seconds to load the next scene because of something that happens here. So here is what I do :

```
            NSString *myURL = [PICURL stringByAppendingString:[[[[levelConfig objectForKey:category] objectForKey:lSet] objectForKey:levelString] objectForKey:@"pic"]];
            UIImage *dYKPic = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:myURL]]];

            if(dYKPic == nil){
                NSString *defaultURL = @"http://www.exampleHP.com/exampleFolder/default.jpg";
                dYKPic = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:defaultURL]]];
            }

                CCTexture2D *tex = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:dYKPic];
                CCSprite *image = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:tex];
                image.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
                image.position = ccp(32,216);
                [self addChild:image z:2];
```

So, it takes 10 seconds, and additionally, the default.jpg is loaded - even though the picture exists - but that just in the case where it takes so long... 70% of the cases it works perfectly normal... So what is wrong ? Where do I release tex ? Immediately after adding the child ?

Answer (score 0):

It has to load the picture. Thats the issue. You either need to load and cache it, store it, or preload it before you need it.

Or one final option is the load it async and just update your view when its finished.

Comment: A) Loading times can vary greatly for a lot of reasons. B) `[UIImage imageWithData:%];` caches things itself. But the system controls when it is released so if the device is low on memory if would be first on the list.